# TableView individual cell listener JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, listener, tableview

So I'm developing a "to-do list" application where there is a TableView containing the tasks to do and in my TableView there is a "deadline" column. I would like that if the deadline date of a task has been passed it makes that specific deadlines date red.

So if the user opens the app on the first of January/2015 and one of his tasks deadline was the 31st of December/2014, its corresponding deadline cell has its text colored in red.

The table is obviously associated to an ObservableList of "Task" objects which have an ObjectProperty "deadline" field.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a [CSS `PseudoClass`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/css/PseudoClass.html) to represent an overdue item. Use a cell factory that sets the pseudoclass state according to whether or not the deadline has passed. You didn't post any code, but the following should help:

```
TableColumn<Task, LocalDate> deadlineColumn = new TableColumn<>("Deadline");
deadlineColumn.setCellValueFactory( cellData -> cellData.getValue().deadlineProperty() ); // or similar...
PseudoClass overdue = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("overdue");
deadlineColumn.setCellFactory(col -> new TableCell<Task, LocalDate>() {
    @Override
    public void updateItem(LocalDate deadline, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(deadline, empty) ;
        if (empty) {
            pseudoClassStateChanged(overdue, false);
            setText(null);
        } else {
            pseudoClassStateChanged(overdue, LocalDate.now().isAfter(deadline));
            setText(deadline.toString());
        }
    }
});
```

And then in an external css file you can do

```
.table-cell:overdue {
    -fx-text-fill: red ;
}
```

Update: here's a complete example, with the CSS shown above in a file called `overdue.css`:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.function.Function;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.css.PseudoClass;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ToDoTable extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TableView<ToDoItem> table = new TableView<>();
        table.getColumns().add(createColumn("Name", ToDoItem::nameProperty));
        TableColumn<ToDoItem, LocalDate> deadlineCol = createColumn("Deadline", ToDoItem::deadlineProperty);
        PseudoClass overdue = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("overdue");
        deadlineCol.setCellFactory(col -> new TableCell<ToDoItem, LocalDate>() {
            @Override
            public void updateItem(LocalDate deadline, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(deadline, empty);
                if (empty) {
                    pseudoClassStateChanged(overdue, false);
                    setText(null);
                } else {
                    pseudoClassStateChanged(overdue, LocalDate.now().isAfter(deadline));
                    setText(deadline.toString());
                }
            }
        });
        table.getColumns().add(deadlineCol);

        for (int i=1; i <= 10; i++) {
            LocalDate deadline = LocalDate.now().plusDays(i - 5);
            ToDoItem item = new ToDoItem("Item "+i, deadline);
            table.getItems().add(item);
        }

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(table);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 800, 600);
        scene.getStylesheets().add("overdue.css");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private static <S,T> TableColumn<S,T> createColumn(String title, Function<S, ObservableValue<T>> property) {
        TableColumn<S,T> col = new TableColumn<>(title);
        col.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> property.apply(cellData.getValue()));
        return col ;
    }


    public static class ToDoItem {
        private final StringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty();
        private final ObjectProperty<LocalDate> deadline = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();

        public ToDoItem(String name, LocalDate deadline) {
            this.name.set(name);
            this.deadline.set(deadline);
        }

        public final StringProperty nameProperty() {
            return this.name;
        }

        public final java.lang.String getName() {
            return this.nameProperty().get();
        }

        public final void setName(final java.lang.String name) {
            this.nameProperty().set(name);
        }

        public final ObjectProperty<LocalDate> deadlineProperty() {
            return this.deadline;
        }

        public final java.time.LocalDate getDeadline() {
            return this.deadlineProperty().get();
        }

        public final void setDeadline(final java.time.LocalDate deadline) {
            this.deadlineProperty().set(deadline);
        }


    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: I put this in but with 
`DeadlineColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("deadline"));` 
instead of 
`deadlineColumn.setCellValueFactory( cellData -> cellData.getValue().deadlineProperty() );`
but it doesn't work. It is entering the else statement but it isn't changing the color. I put an "overdue.css" file with the code you mentioned in the root directory, if it doesn't find it it would throw an illegalArgumentException right?

Comment: How are you attaching the CSS? To the Scene? Or to another parent?

Comment: Also, you can eliminate the css file just to test things with `if (LocalDate.now().isAfter(deadline)) { setStyle("-fx-text-fill: red;");} else { setStyle("");}` (instead of the call to `psuedoClassStateChanged(...);`) Moving this to an external CSS file is much more preferable though.

Comment: Added a complete example.

Comment: thanks a lot for the example that really helped me understand it better. Only thing that wasn't working was that `scene.getStylesheets().add("overdue.css");` was giving me `WARNING: com.sun.javafx.css.StyleManager loadStylesheetUnPrivileged`, fixed that by replacing it with `scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("overdue.css").toExternalForm());` but it's probably a noob workaround. Thanks again!

Comment: That's actually the correct way to go; I was just using a shortcut for the example.